# document.write() in IE executive order is not the same by others

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, document.write

```
   <script>
      document.write("before write h1.js"+"<br/>");
      document.write("<script  src='h" + "1.js'><\/script>");
      document.write("after write h1.js" +"<br/>");
   </script>
```

---

h1.js file:

This is h1.js

---

In IE the result will be:

1. before write h1.js
2. after write h1.js
3. This is h1.js

Firefox Chrome Safari Opera:

1. before write h1.js
2. This is h1.js
3. after write h1.js

How could I write a script to make it the same order in all brower.

Comment: you may get unexpected result becoz that "This is h1.js" is not JS code. the content of h1.js must be JS code i think.

Comment: @PaulDinh it is, Internet Explorer just executes the external js only after the document has been written to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work the same in all browsers:

```
<script>
    document.write('before h1.js');
</script>
<script src="h1.js"></script>
<script>
    document.write('after h1.js');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this: IE executes your script, adds the new content to `document` and then examines the content.

So if your `h1.js` script writes to the document, then this code will be executed *after* your JavaScript finishes. This is due to the synchronous nature of JavaScript.

If you want to avoid this, the usual solution is to have `h1.js` define a function which you can call at the appropriate time. Then, you can write:

```
<script>document.write("<script  src='h" + "1.js'><\/script>");</script>
<script>
    document.write("before write h1.js"+"<br/>");
    document.write(h1());
    document.write("after write h1.js" +"<br/>");
</script>
```

The first script block allows you to load the function. After it finishes, IE will parse the new code. Then it will run the second code block and the function will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/) blog post by Steve Souders to understand problems in techniques to load scripts asynchronously and ensure order.

From the same reference

> **document.write Script Tag** – Write the  HTML into the
> page using document.write. This only loads script without blocking in
> IE.

And this is the reason why you are able to see such a varied order of execution. script load didn't block `after write h1.js` from execution. It happens only in IE